# minTime and maxTime of jquery DateTimePicker not respected

Tags: datetimepicker

I'm trying to work with http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ .

I have the following code:

```
var TIMESETTING = {format:'H:i',datepicker:false,scrollMonth: false,scrollInput: false,minTime:'07:00',maxTime:'09:00',formatTime:'H:i'};
$('#date').datetimepicker(TIMESETTING);
```

But when I run it, ALL the time slots of the text field are greyed out and not clickable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
var TIMESETTING = {format:'H:i',datepicker:false,scrollMonth:false,scrollInput: false,minTime:'07:00',maxTime:'09:00',formatTime:'H:i'};
$('#date').datetimepicker(TIMESETTING);
```

In your options object you are setting format as well as formatTime, is this of a specific reason? Does it work if you utilize allowTimes instead?

Comment: Allow time works, but I prefer not to use it.  Setting none, one or both of format and formatTime has no effect on my error

Comment: Looking at the source code it seems that the current options for minTime and maxTime are being overriden, a shallow solution could be to force-enable the options using: disabledMinTime:false and disabledMaxTime:false explicitly. Pardon the bad formatting i am on an iPad. Hope that is of Help!

Comment: disabledMaxTime and disabledMinTime didn't help. I think I have to manually add xdsoft_time_disabled class